# after clone: npm install produces different package-lock file

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, diff, package-lock.json

I'm using npm 5.6.0 and node v6.9.5 on OSX El Capitan 10.11.6.

**Scenario**: I have a nodejs project where a *package-lock.json* is created after every npm install as expected. The project, including the *package-lock.json*, is checked into a repository and afterwards cloned into a different location (same machine, same OS, same npm & node versions).

**Problem**: However, this time when starting npm install, the *package-lock.json* is different in terms of order of dependencies.

**Background**: Now this normally wouldn't be a problem but I need to calculate a checksum over all of the files on the git pre-commit hook to signal in the app, that the project has not been changed when it is cloned from the repository and would like to include *package-lock.json* into that checksum.

Therefore:

working folder: -> npm install -> *package-lock.json* -> checksum -> ABCD1234 -> commit & push
cloned folder: clone -> npm install -> *package-lock.json* -> checksum -> 9876EFGH

and the only difference (using filemerge tool on OS X) is the different order of one single dependency in the *package-lock.json* file, every other file is exactly the same.

Shouldn't the two *package-lock.json* files be exactly the same? Or did I miss a specific npm concept that does not guarantee that?

Any help / hint is appreciated, thank you!

(Normally I would attach the *package-lock.json* as code however this file is too long so I will provide a screenshot of the actual differences)

[image: diff of *package-lock.json* - only differences]

Comment: Welcome to the shitstorm that is NPM.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to determine or change what is in package-lock.json, use `npm install`, but (since npm 5.7.1) if you want to make sure you're getting exactly what is in the provided package-lock.json, use `npm ci`

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html